# Convert a column from a dataframe into a matrix Aij

Tags: python

I'm struggling with an issue.

I have dataset bellow and I try to  create a matrix from Atom_combine column like:

```
____|N16|CA16|C16| ... |C18|O18|N19
N16
CA16
C16
...
C18
O18
N19_______________________________
```

Can I get please an example or directions where I should start ?

Each intersection ultimately will be the distance between each atom (distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2)).

I managed to complete the calculation proof of concept for the distance but can't find a way to create the matrix ...

[image: sample dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `cdist` to find distance matrix (array).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 2]])
D = cdist(X, X, metric='euclidean') # your distance matrix
```

So for you example, you array `X` is `X = np.array(df[['x_coord', 'y_coord', 'z_coord']])` where `df` is your dataframe. You can convert to dataframe with corresponded indices and columns of `Atom_combine` as

```
Df = pd.DataFrame(D, index=list(df['Atom_combine']), columns=list(df['Atom_combine']))
```

Comment: Distance is not the problem ... creating of the matrix having colnames as the column from dataframe and rownames as the column from dataframe as well ...

Comment: After having the matrix than I'm filling up the matrix with distances for each Aij

Comment: Can you use pandas dataframe to do the task instead? I updated my solution so that you have index and column of `Atom_combine`

Comment: now I can do DataFrame.as_matrix(columns=None) and have a matrix. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Hope that helps!